# Jframe (Tablas)

Tags: java

Como puedo insertar datos en un Jtable con POO
Creo mi Jtable

```
DefaultTableModel dtabla=new DefaultTableModel();
    public Registro_Revistas() {
        initComponents();
        jTable1.setModel(dtabla);
        String[] titulos =new String[]{"Codigo de la Revista","Fecha de Publicacion","Editorial","Nombre de revista","Cantidad de ejemplares","Autor","Descripcion","Estado","Observacion"};
        dtabla.setColumnIdentifiers(titulos);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);

    }
```

Luego en mi boton tengo esto

```
String Obj[]=new String[19];
       Obj[0]=jTextField1.getText();
       Obj[1]=jTextField2.getText();
       Obj[2]=jTextField3.getText();
       Obj[3]=jTextField4.getText();
       Obj[4]=jTextField5.getText();
       Obj[5]=jTextField8.getText();
       Obj[6]=jTextField7.getText();
       Obj[7]=jTextField6.getText();
       Obj[8]=jTextField9.getText();
       dtabla.addRow(Obj);
```

Mi pregunta es Como puedo meter los valores en el Jtable con objetos con seters y geters .. porque si ingresa pero quisiera hacerlo con con POO Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Lo podrias hacer de esta manera para llenar la tabla yo veo que ya tienes creado el objeto `jTable1` entonces solo es de inicializarlo, si quieres tambien generar las columnas solo pones , el `array` de las columnas

```
String Obj[]=new String[19];
   Obj[0]=jTextField1.getText();
   Obj[1]=jTextField2.getText();
   Obj[2]=jTextField3.getText();
   Obj[3]=jTextField4.getText();
   Obj[4]=jTextField5.getText();
   Obj[5]=jTextField8.getText();
   Obj[6]=jTextField7.getText();
   Obj[7]=jTextField6.getText();
   Obj[8]=jTextField9.getText();
   dtabla.addRow(Obj);

   dtabla= new DefaultTableModel(Obj.toArray());
   jTable1 = new JTable(dtabla);
```